# Robotframework not able to open browser

Tags: robotframework

I am facing the below issue:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
 (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

my PIP list as follows:

```
robotframework 3.2.1
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.3.1
selenium 3.141.0
```

I am using Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: What version of Chrome are using? Error message suggests that you version of chromedriver and Chrome don't match.

Comment: The error seems very clear: you have a version mismatch between chrome and chrome driver.

Comment: My chrome version is 81.0 64 bit

Comment: And your chromedriver supports Chrome v74 - upgrade it (or downgrade your browser )

Comment: Upgrade your webdriver, would be resolved your issue. I also had same and it was resolved once upgrade chrome web driver.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your Chromederiver to the same version as is your Chrome:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: why was this downvoted ? Its exactly the right answer. Error message says "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74". Thats rather old chromedriver considering that current chrome release is >80. Chrome by default auto-updates itself (and op didnt mention that was disabled) so its pretty safe to assume that chrome is newer than chromedriver ..